# WPF , MVVM , MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I got a MasterPage UserControl which contain 3 user controls (and 3 viewmodels)

```
MasterView:
 -> MenuView (-> MenuViewModel )
 -> InfoView (-> InfoViewModel )
 -> SliderView (-> SliderViewModel )
```

In slider view i got a listbox with SelectedItem Property binded to a SelectedItem Property in the view model (SliderViewModel)

when the SelectedItem changes , i want to bubble it all the way to InfoViewModel and to update InfoView.

I can do it with events like i did many times in winforms but i'm looking for best practice way of the mvvm pattern.

another small question is , should i create a viewmodel for the MasterView page as well ? although it does not contain anything beside combining 3 users controls together.

your help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the best MVVM best practise in this scenario but I can think of one way of doing it through MVVM.

You can create a `MasterViewModel` and expose a property in masterViewModel for communication between other view models. Like below

```
class MasterViewModel
{
    MenuViewModel;
    InfoViewModel;
    SliderViewModel;

    public CommunicationProperty 
    {
       set
       {
       InforViewModel.SomeProperty = value;
       }
    }
}

class SliderViewModel
{
    pubic SliderViewModel(MasterViewModel masterViewModel)
    {
        //hold reference of master view model in a variable  
    }

    public SelectedItem
    {
        set
        {
            // change the info view model via master view model
            masterViewModel.CommunicationProperty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is few options:

1. You may declare SelectedItem as dependency property in your view
   model class (if it is inherited from DependencyObject)
2. You may declare SelectedItem as regular property and make your view model
   class to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire
   PropertyChanged event in setter.

WPF has new a lot of new concepts but still communicates with business logic via events.